# How to distinguish missing data from the value 0 by using the independent variables

Tags: missing-data

I have an independent variable and a dependent variable. The dependent variable is about $0$, and is often precisely $0$, but $0$ is also the value given to the response when data has been missing.

All I know is that if data is missing for one value (say, $x$) of the independent variable, then it should also be missing for values of the independent variable in a small neighborhood around $x$.

Using this information, is it possible to determine which values are actually $0$ and which denote missing data? Statistically speaking, of course?

Comment: Since the dependent variable can be "precisely $0$" as well as missing, you simply have no information that would run counter to either of the most extreme hypotheses: namely, all zeros represent true zeros or all zeros represent missing values.  You can't manufacture information you don't have.